# Where is good place for Interface class header files in layered architecture with c++?

Tags: architecture, dependencies, header-files

I have confused dependency of call and association in previous question.
So I edited my question then be able to answer my question.

Let's suppose we have 2 layers which are upper layer and lower layer.
And upper layer can use lower layer but opposite is not permitted.

There is B_interface. It's implementation Class B resides in lower layer and it's user Class A resides in upper layer.

At that time, where is the best place for B_interface (B_interface.h)?

Case 1:
[image]

In case 1, B Interface file resides in lower layer together with it's implementation Class B

Case 2:
[image]
In case 2, B_Interface.h file resides in upper layer which looks like low cohesion because B_Interface's implementation is in the lower layer.

So, which one is the better choice for this? Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The important point is dependency's direction of layer. If layer dependency is upper to lower then you should choice case 1, but lower to upper then should choice case 2.

Don't confuse call dependency with the association dependency. The dependency we have to focus is not call dependency but the association dependency. These two dependencies's directions can be same or opposite.

When you design the layer which has dependency upper to lower but the class in lower layer has dependency with the class in upper class, it's violation of dependency direction so what should you do?

You can invert dependency using interface like Case 1 to Case 2.